# Very basic question regarding $\text{Tor}$ groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm trying to calculate the groups $\text{Tor}_0(H_0(\mathbb{RP^3}) ; \mathbb{Z}/2)$ and $\text{Tor}_1(H_0(\mathbb{RP^3}) ; \mathbb{Z}/2)$, but I seem to be making some sort of basic mistake.

I know the following:
$$H_0(\mathbb{RP^3}) = \mathbb{Z}$$

I take the following free resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$:
$$0 \rightarrow 0 \xrightarrow{0} \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow H_0(\mathbb{RP^3})  =  \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0 $$
I then replace this final group with $0$ and tensor by $\mathbb{Z}/2$:
$$0 \rightarrow 0 \xrightarrow{0} \mathbb{Z}/2 \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow 0 $$

Then, I believe $\text{Tor}_0(H_0(\mathbb{RP^3}) ; \mathbb{Z}/2)$ = $\ker(0: 0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2) = 0$; $\text{Tor}_1(H_0(\mathbb{RP^3}) ; \mathbb{Z}/2) = \text{coker}(0: 0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2) = \mathbb{Z}/2 / \{0\} = \mathbb{Z}/2$.

However, this contradicts the theorem that:

$$\text{Tor}_0(A,B) \cong A \otimes B$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your sequences are shifted by one place. To compute the derived functor of $M \to A\otimes M$, start with a free (or injective or projective, depending on the functor in question) resolution $0 \to M \to F^0 \to F^1 \to \cdots$, and look at the homology of $0 \to A\otimes F^0 \to A\otimes F^1 \to \cdots$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be a bit more careful about which homology you take. If you have a projective/ free resolution $P$ of your module, then the Tor groups are defined as
$$ Tor_i(A,B)\cong H_i(P \otimes B) $$
This gives you $\operatorname{Tor}_0(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/2) = H_0(\dots \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2 \rightarrow 0)=\operatorname{ker}(\mathbb{Z}/2\rightarrow 0)=\mathbb{Z}/2$ as it should be, and analogously $\operatorname{Tor}_1(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/2) = H_1(\dots \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2 \rightarrow 0)=0$, as one espects since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a projective module.

I think your mistake was that only replaced $A$ itself by $0$, instead of leaving it out completely.